# Does finetuning a host make sense when using docker?

Tags: docker, mongodb

I have a dedicated machine for a mongodb-instance. For ease of deployment, I am running that mongodb from within a docker-container.

At the mongo-manuals they suggest some settings, one should adopt for his/her OS: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-checklist-operations/#operating-system-configuration

They suggest turning off transparent hugepages, adjusting file handles and so on.

My question is: does this even have an effect when using docker or do I need to avoid docker at all to make use of the full performance (incl adjustments) of my machine?

Edit:\ For more context - I am looking into this as I am currently unhappy with my query performance and already made sure that the queries are not further optimisable / are already fully indexed).